# Nginx Map Regex & MTLS

Tags: regex, nginx, client-certificates

i need to change outgoing format for client-certificate:

here's what nginx does with

```
$ssl_client_raw (\x0A):

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\x0AMIIGujCCBaKgAwIBAgITWg...



$ssl_client_escaped_cert (%20 | %0A):

-----BEGIN%20CERTIFICATE-----%0AMIIGujCCBaKgAwIBAgITWg...



$ssl_client_cert (\x0A | \x09):

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\x0A\x09MIIGujCCBaKgAwIBAgITWg...
```

what i need is a "clean" text/certificate and i thought it would be a good idea to do it with map in nginx:

```
map $ssl_client_raw_cert $regex {
    "~(-+BEGIN\sCERTIFICATE-+)|(?:\\x0A)(.{64})|(?:\\x0A)(-+END\sCERTIFICATE-+)(?:\\x0A)"    $1$2$3;
}

.
.
.

location / {
    ...
    proxy_set_header        X-SSL-CERT $regex;
    ...
}
```

so... the first regex works so far but nginx stock at second (btw: whats up with regex parameters "global" and "multiline" ?)

Any ideas how to get it work ?

Thanks a lot...

tried multiple nginx versions, multiple regex... now i use 1.24 on a dev-system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found it with OpenResty and Lua:

```
   location / {
        set $ssl_cert "${ssl_client_raw_cert}";

        access_by_lua_block {
            ngx.log(ngx.DEBUG, "*** start access_by_lua_block ***")
            local cert = ngx.var.ssl_cert
            local modified_cert = string.gsub(cert, "[\n\r]", "")
            ngx.log(ngx.DEBUG, "DEBUG modiified_cert: ", modified_cert)
            ngx.var.ssl_cert = modified_cert
            ngx.log(ngx.DEBUG, "*** end access_by_lua_block ***")
        }

        proxy_set_header    Host $host;
        proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header    X-SSL-CERT $ssl_cert;
        proxy_pass          https://yourmachine;
    }
```

Thanks for the hint Jeremy:

Unfortunately, I cannot say where the “misbehavior” of nginx occurs. What we discovered, however, is that the certificate from Nginx towards the backend system contains line breaks, which were not processed correctly by the backend system due to the characters "\x0A" (Hex for Line Feed).

We couldn't remove the unnecessary characters directly in Nginx (or I did something wrong), only with OpenResty ( = Nginx & Lua component) could the line feeds be removed with a simple "replace \n or \r with nothing", or "replace Hex \x0A (Line Feed) or Hex \x0D (Carriage return) with nothing".

```
local modified_cert = string.gsub(cert, "[\n\r]", "")
```

The Nginx variable `$ssl_client_raw_cert` is converted to `$ssl_cert`, then processed in the Lua block and passed on to the backend system via `proxy_set_header X-SSL-CERT $ssl_cert`.

Hope that helps a little bit.

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?